# Trying to link my HTML form to a view function in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I've been trying to create a user registration page and have gotten the form itself and the render for the form set up. I have also gotten the form to save user input as POST, but haven't been able to send that info to a view function I have created to save that info to a database.

Here is my html/css template form:(`userinfo.html`)

```html
<div>
    {% block content %}
    <form action="register" method="post" name="Userinfo" id="Userinfo">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name..">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="DOB">Date Of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" id="DOB" name="DOB" placeholder="The Date you were born">

    <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

The name of my view function is `register` and here it is:(`views.py`)

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
        last_name = request.POST['last_name'],
        date_of_birth = request.POST['DOB'],
        email = request.POST['email']
        newuser= User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name, email=email)
        newuser.save()
        print('user created')
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        return render(request,'register.html')
```

This is supposed to save the user input into Django's user database table.

How would I go about linking the form to the view I have set up?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the name of your register view is also register, i.e.,

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    ...
]
```

then you can just change the form tag as follows:

```html
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post" name="Userinfo" id="Userinfo">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name..">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="last_name" placeholder="Your last name..">

    ...

  </form>
```

Note the change in the name for the inputs to `first_name` and `last_name` so the match your request.POST['first_name'] and request.POST['last_name']

The `{% url 'register' %}` tells Django to look for a url path that has a view with the name register.

Comment: That's not an answer David is looking for.

Comment: @raphael would that just link the url's together or would it also link to the views.py file as well?

Comment: Yes, @David_Codes, it will link to the views.py as well.

Comment: @David_Codes, the ` [03/Feb/2022 16:01:23] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1399` means that the page was indeed found.  I've updated the answer with the corrected html.

Comment: Was hoping for the page to submit user input into my views.py file

Comment: @David_Codes, that's exactly what this should do.  Did you update your code. Please edit your question with your updated code, maybe I can find the error.

Comment: One sec I'll put the code in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241707/discussion-between-raphael-and-david-codes).

Comment: Tried to do that can't edit my main post because of a suggested edit I cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that `firstname` from `form` is not the same as `first_name` you seek in `views`. You have to fetch exactly the same data, as you place in `html`. You can always

```
print(request.POST)
```

to see what the `POST` dictionary has :)

With that fixed it should work for now.

Comment: Just fixed it and reran the server. Still having the same thing, it is just showing me that a post request has been made, but do not see what and where that data is or where it is going. I have also added in the print(request.POST) to my view file and it seems like they are not linked together. I am getting this message when I submit something: [03/Feb/2022 16:01:23] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1399

Comment: Are you using 'register.html' in view, but your form is in `userinfo.html`? Are you including that form inside `register.html`? You have to render that form, only then `view` can fetch `POST` coming from it.

Comment: I was playing around with the idea of using a model form earlier but decided to use a custom html/css form instead. Also I have it set in the views to go back to my home page once form is submitted, but when I submit the form nothing happens. Also wouldn't I not be able to see the form if it isn't rendered?

Comment: That is ok to make custom `html form`, but if the `form` is not in the template using in that view, then it's not possible to fetch data from that `form`. You need to include it in somehow. Share both `html` in main post, so I can help you. Especially `register.html`.

Comment: Here is register.html it does not have anything:                                                      
 {%block title %} Create an account {% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Register</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}

Comment: Here is the main file I have been working with:                                                                            
  <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post" name="Userinfo" id="Userinfo">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Your first name..">
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Your last name..">
    ... Posted as much of it as comments will let me.

Comment: Please, edit main post - that one with the question.

Comment: Couldn't post it to the main post but I was able to edit your answer and put it there.

Comment: Apparently, it is not visible, and I cannot add it to my main post as there is a suggested edit I can't get around.

Comment: You are probably seeing your old form. Change `render(request,'register.html')` to `render(request,'userinfo.html')` so you will see if the custom one is rendered.

Comment: I did and nothing happened, not sure what isn't connecting.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer
use `(request.POST.get)` or `(request.POST.items()}`

If you print this it return a query dict that contain all inputs in your form so you should turn it to regular dic :

```
data = {key: value for key, value in request.POST.items()}
```

also before doing that you should name all your inputs in your template:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="text" name="age">
```

so "firsname" will be your key in your dictionary
your dic result will be:
{"firstname":"input-name" , "lastname":"input-lname" , "age":"20"}

You can also use:

```
(request.POST.get("firstname"))
```

to get single input from form with str type.

I this way you should name your in input:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

Sorry for my bad English