# Can't render out user specific content

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to render out model objects that are unique to a user. All methods I've found haven't worked and I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. What is supposed to happen is that you can see the jobs you've posted in the manage-jobs.html template. Also I've removed all of my failed attempts to render out user specific content, it's not that I haven't tried to do this by myself. Thanks.

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, verbose_name="Company/Employer")
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    area_of_filming = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Area Of Filming", default="")
    contact_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Contact Email', max_length=60, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, default='', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Are you using FilmLink as an employee?')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'is_employee']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("post_jobs", "Can post jobs"),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_perms(self, perm):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def manage_jobs(request):
    if request.user.is_employee:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        context = {"form":form}
        return render(request, 'employer/manage-jobs.html', context)
```

manage-jobs.html

```
<button id="myBtn">Post A Job</button>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times</span>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div id="company-container">
            <p>Employer Name</p>
            <p id="employer">{{form.company}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="role-container">
            <p>Role (e.g. Actor, Director)</p>
            <p id="role">{{form.role}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="area-of-filming-container">
            <p>Area Of Production/Filming</p>
            <p id="area-of-filming">{{form.area_of_filming}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="contact-email-container">
            <p>Contact Email</p>
            <p id="contact-email">{{form.contact_email}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="description-container">
            <p>Description Of Job</p>
            <p id="description">{{form.description}}</p>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="post-job">Publish Job</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that this should render out "jobs". This is only going to render out one job but I am going to assume you intend to solve that after you can actually see content on your screen.

I think the problem is to do with your frontend form.
Note that on your views.py function `manage_jobs`, that if the user is not an employee you create a form by POST, but the frontend is not connecting to that request.POST.

I am not sure how your urls.py file looks, but you want to link to that views.py call from your form.

In your `<form action="{% url 'manage_jobs' %}" method="POST">`

This may not be your solution, but I would check out [this anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977918/trying-to-link-my-html-form-to-a-view-function-in-django).

Hope you can figure it out!

Comment: I updated the form to link to the manage_jobs page, exactly as you said, but I'm still wondering now how to render out the jobs themselves. should I say something like jobs = Job.objects.filter(user = request.user), and then render jobs in the context dictionary?

Comment: I think this problem will go beyond the scope of what I can answer in a comment.

I would say that filtering is a correct approach and would work. Need to remember that filtering would return an array, which is useful and you could use that on the front-end. 

[Django For Loops](https://pythonguides.com/django-for-loop/).

I think that you django for loops would allow you to render them on the frontend. Although, I, personally, would not want to have more than one form on a page so maybe could reconsider about how displaying them.

But that is down to design choice.